# how can I identify what is being downloaded on my mac ethernet connection

Tags: networking, mac, ethernet

Mac o/s 10.11.6 on 2015(late) Retina 5K 27" iMac i7 four cores, 24G memory. 240G-SSD,  Linksys 1900AC router thru ARRIS modem on Comcast internet service.
Using Net Monitor software on my ethernet is see downloads, but nothing pops up(zero identity is presented on the download activity).  Its not mail or s/w updates i would like to know what is being sent(received) yo my iMac

I see a download coming in and have NO idea what it is.  Just a key pounder interested in what is being introduced to my mach.

I am not adverse in purchasing a S/W tool to provide  the answer

Comment: Little Snitch will show you pretty much what, where & who [but software recs are off-topic on here, so I'm not posting as an answer]

Comment: Thank you, I have little snitch installed.  Will have to educate myself in it's uses

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, the exact problem is, you failed to find the download button in your Safari. If you are running OS X or its later versions, this article will help you out. 
https://www.macworld.com/article/3153064/browsers/where-to-find-safari-s-downloads-list.html

If that works for you, you can thank me as well

Regards
Daisy

Comment: Hey Steve,You have not replied. I wish your problem is resolved.please do share how have you managed to tackle it?